# Attempt to break deadlock?

Tags: database, oracle

i want replace schema....drop first, then import with impdp....

```
  SQL>drop user usertest cascade;
    ....hang no respond...
```

check alert log :

```
ORA-00060: Deadlock detected. More info in file /u01/app/oracle /diag/rdbms/procu/procu/trace/procu_ora_2833.trc



    Output from : /procu_ora_2833.trc

    9 : DB session is not attached to XS Session
    END OF PROCESS STATE

    *** 2015-03-02 08:53:25.276
```

Attempting to break deadlock by signaling ORA-00060

Please help me out in this???

Comment: Was there anything useful in the trace file?

Comment: nope,this is all i have

Comment: will killing all sessions using the schema objects can help in this..

Comment: Which user are you logged in as when you run the drop command? Can you check which session are logged in and are accessing the schema objects, and kill the session? The issue here though would be how to stop new sessions connecting and aquiring "locks".

Comment: you should add it as answer